# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Crashlytics"

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, crashlytics

I am developing react-native app.

I followed the firebase instruction adding my iOS app to my firebase project.

In my Podfile, I have:

```
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

when I run `pod install` I keep getting the error saying "CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Crashlytics".
[image]

Xcode version 11.7, target iOS10.1

Why I get that error and how to get rid of it?

(I tried run `pod update 'Firebase'`, I get:

> [!] The `Firebase` Pod is not installed and cannot be update)

Comment: Run `pod update Firebase` to update all Firebase pods.

Comment: I updated my question, I actually tried that, with and without the quotation mark, same error `The 'Firebase' Pod is not installed and cannot be update`.  Also tried adding the `pod 'Firebase/Core' `, no luck either.

Comment: Make sure that your project's minimum deployment target is at least iOS 9 (see Firebase/Crashlytics [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#crashlytics)) If that's OK, then try first to update the cocoapods spec repo by running `pod repo update` and then `pod install`.

Comment: Thanks, in xcode I have target iOS 10.1 but it is a react native project on the upper layer I am not sure in react-native is there a place to set the target or is it enough I only make sure xcode project use iOS 10.1. Anyway, target is 10.1 in xcode project.

Comment: Check your `Podfile` file in your project root. It should have something like `platform :ios, '10.1'`.

Comment: Good point! I checked my Podfile, it is ios9.0 there. I thought xcode target value would automatically be applied to Podfile, but seems not...

Comment: @gcharita could you please make an answer? That solved my issue. And if possible it would be nice if you could give a few words about the platform version in Podfile is not associated with the xcode target version.

Comment: Please do not show images of text.  Copy the text into the question so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: In such cases You must try to use lower version for that library and then install pod... This will fix issue.  This process helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your project's minimum deployment target (the one that referenced in your `Podfile`) is at least iOS 9 (see Firebase/Crashlytics [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#crashlytics))

Unfortunately when cocoapods initially create the `Podfile`, doesn't take into account your projects minimum deployment target. Instead adds a default value in a comment.

The first time that you run `pod install` you will get a warning about not specified minimum deployment target. Also cocoapods [documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform) doesn't mention anything regarding this behavior.

So, you have to have to manually edit your Podfile and add something like this:

```rb
platform :ios, '10.1'
```

Comment: @Kudos what error are you getting? Could you provide your project configuration? (deployment target, Podfile)

Comment: @Kudos minimum deployment target of Firebase/Crashlytics seems to be covered by iOS 10.1. (just tested) Maybe you have other conflicts in dependencies. Maybe you didn't add this line at the root of your `Podfile` or maybe 10.1 isn't the minimum deployment target of your project. I can't really help if you don't share more info.

Answer (score 5):

In my case

```
pod install
```

threw an error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Crashlytics":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Crashlytics (= 10.15.0)

  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Crashlytics

    firebase_crashlytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`) was resolved to 3.4.3, which depends on
      Firebase/Crashlytics (= 10.16.0)

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Crashlytics, Firebase/Crashlytics (= 10.15.0), Firebase/Crashlytics (= 10.16.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

So I had to execute the following commands, then it worked:

```
pod repo update 
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and then again

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

No issue with the deployment target but got the same error. It was working with the following versions of Firebase

```
 pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 3.0.0'
 pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '~> 7.0.0'
```

When I added a new dependency and run pod install, It was showing the error for Firebase. So, I used the >= 0 in place of the version.

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '>= 0'
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '>= 0'
```

This will install the latest version for all Firebase dependencies.